# Can I run a web site from my home network without jeapordizing other computers on my LAN?

Tags: security, iis, router, port, forwarding

I have a home LAN with 5 computers and a NAS, all connected to a Linksys router which is connected to my Cox cable modem.

I'm interested in having one of my computers run an IIS-based web site and to have it be accessible to the internet with a static IP.  However, I do not want o jeapordize the safety of the other computers on my home network!

Is there anyway to do this safely, or as safe as possible?  I may also like to run an FTP server from this computer.  Finally, optionally I would like to allow remote access to this computer from the internet--but it seems to me that that may increase the security risk to the other computers substantially.

Comment: nothing is secure if it has an ip address, but you need to weigh risks vs rewards!  Your risks are low(er) since your not a target rich environment, as in nobody is going to put a concerted effort to to hack you, with mostly just basic firewall stuff and don't use the server to surf the web you should be safe.  I'm not sure of the rewards in your case!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Keep your router software updated
- Configure the server with a static IP
- Configure the router to only require the bare minimum ports
- Only enable the bare minimum services on IIS and the server
- Enable the Windows firewall and configure port access to only the required services.
- Keep Windows and all Applications updated on patches and Anti-Virus
- Only use IIS 6 or later (Windows XP/Windows 2003 or later)
- Use very long and complex passwords for all accounts on the server and the router
- Keep your web Application software updated. Software like WordPress is a big target.

Comment: Consider adding another firewall between the PC and keeping it on a separate LAN.  This is just in case it becomes infected it will not have direct access to the other PCs in the house to spread.

Comment: Thanks for the insights, is LogMein better to use than Microsoft RDS (Remote Desktop Services)?

Comment: LogMeIn just allows you to easily and securely configure access to the server without opening your firewall. You install LogMeIn's client and it maintains a connection to their servers which you can then gain access through the website. Try both and see what you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

just pop the pc you want to act as your server in your DMZ.  this is configured through your router.

Comment: and make sure you use a strong pw for the router!

Comment: The DMZ is essentially running without a firewall.  I suggest using port forwarding instead to reduce risk.